# Path of element in api tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to get some data from an api, the api structure looks like :

```
{
    "data": {
        "student": {
            "id": 3568,
            "name": "Alain"
        },
        "notes": {
            "current_page": 1,
            "total": 2,
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 875472,
                    "subject": "maths",
                    "note": 18
                },
                {
                    "id": 75472,
                    "subject": "music",
                    "note": 16
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

In my network preview tab i can see the data cause the status code is 200, but i cant display the data because i am not sure i am using the correct path to set the states **response...**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        student_infs: '',
        notes: []
    }
}

Api.fetchNotes(newData.params)
.catch( error => {
    if (typeof error.message !== "undefined"){
    newData.config.formMessage = {
        message : error.message,
        success : false,
    }
    this.setState(newData)
    }
    return {data:{data:[]}}
})
.then( response => {
    if(response.data.status === 200){
        if(response.data.status === 'success'){
            return response.data.data;
        }
        this.setState({
            student_infs: response.data.notes,
            notes: [...response.data.notes.data]
        });
    }
}).catch(error => {
    //console.log(error)
})
```

Comment: So when the response status is "success" you don't want to call `setState`? I don't understand. Secondly, `reponse.data.student` does not take into account that you have a nested `data` property.

Comment: I have added a condition response.data.status === 200 so i can call it anyways

Comment: So? What do you mean? You still `return` without calling `setState` when the `status` is "success".

Comment: should i call it inside the response status is "success" condition, i did but it didn't work

Comment: That's one step, and now the other half of my first comment needs also to be taken into account.

Comment: honestly i didn't get it, do you mean that the path is incorrect? i tried response.data.data... but in vain

Comment: This should be a piece of cake to check with a debugger. Did you inspect the response at a break point? Just analyse the `response` and gradually drill down until you have the correct expression to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Once check whether you parsed the json  request to js object .

And you are returning after checking success , and the setState is not reachable